# Prevent Add-Member cmdlet from invoking ScriptProperty members when adding new member

Tags: powershell

I have come across this when testing some scripts on Windows 10 Preview under PowerShell 5.0, but I was also able to invoke it on some machines with Win 8.1 and PS4.0 (not all of them tho).

Basically when calling Add-Member cmdlet all ScriptProperty members from that object are being invoked, which is something that is not happening under PS 2 or 3.

When this code is executed:

```
$global:BaseObject = New-Object PSObject
$global:BaseObject | Add-Member ScriptProperty "Test" { Write-Warning "I shouldn't see this during next Add-Member call!" }
$global:BaseObject | Add-Member NoteProperty "Test2" 2
```

...you can see warning message logged into console after last Add-Member call.

Any idea why is this happening and how to prevent it? Or why this does happen on some machines and not on others with the same PowerShell version?

**Update:**

As mentioned below this looks like a bug in PowerShell. I was able to find that it occurs in PS 4 as well as PS 5 Preview if you have System.Management.Automation.dll in version 6.3.9600.17400 or newer (for some reason some of our 8.1 machines have it in 6.3.9600.17090 which works correctly). I will file a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: When you use `Add-Member`, are you seeing the resultant object, as though you had called it with `-PassThru`? Is the code you posted the actual code you're running? In PS4 I cannot repro in ISE nor in console host.

Comment: Bit of a guess, but is it just returning the object after each operation? Does it still happen if you pipe to `Out-Null`?

Comment: @briantist I'm not using -PassThru, using that actually invokes scriptproperty 6 times :)

Comment: @arco444 Just tried it and Out-Null makes not difference.

Comment: Can you check the value of `$WarningPreference`?

Comment: @MickyBalladelli it's set to Continue on both systems where the problem occurs and where it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are hitting a bug.

Using V5 Preview you can avoid seeing the warning by implementing the following [ugly] workaround:

```
$WarningPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$global:BaseObject = New-Object PSObject
$global:BaseObject | Add-Member ScriptProperty "Test" { Write-Warning "I shouldn't see this during next Add-Member call!" }
$global:BaseObject | Add-Member NoteProperty "Test2" 2
$WarningPreference = "Continue"
```

However you will see the following when you invoke the object `$global:BaseObject`

```
WARNING: I shouldn't see this during next Add-Member call!
WARNING: I shouldn't see this during next Add-Member call!
WARNING: I shouldn't see this during next Add-Member call!
WARNING: I shouldn't see this during next Add-Member call!
WARNING: I shouldn't see this during next Add-Member call!

Test                                                                          Test2
----                                                                          -----
                                                                              2
```

And `$global:BaseObject.PsObject.methods` shows 4 methods, + the ScriptProperty, makes 5.
So it seems like it's invoking the ScriptProperty for every method of the object.

If you now invoke `$global:BaseObject.Test2` the warning won't display.

```
$global:BaseObject.Test2
2
```

And if you invoke `$global:BaseObject.Test` the warning appears as it should.

Hopefully this helps someone analyze further and provide a nicer fix.